# Save to external text-file from runnable jar

Tags: java, file, executable-jar

I have trouble getting my runnable jar file to write to an external text file. My intent is to store data in a text file that is in the same folder as the runnable jar (NOT inside the jar); each line is one dataset, new datasets are appended at the end of the existing file.
I have tried several different approaches that work perfectly when I run the code from Eclipse but as soon as it is exported to a runnable jar (also via Eclipse) it does no longer change the text file.

Here are the things I tried:

1. OutputStreamWriter

   ```
    public void writeData(String dataset) {
     try {      
       URL               url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("datasets.txt");
       OutputStream       os = new FileOutputStream(url.getFile(), true);
       OutputStreamWriter ow = new OutputStreamWriter(os);

       String line = "\n" + dataset; 
       ow.append(line);
       ow.close();
       os.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   ```
2. BufferedWriter

   ```
   public void writeData(String dataset) {
     try {
        URL           fileUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("datasets.txt")
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileUrl.getPath(), true));

        writer.newLine(); 
        writer.write(dataset);
        writer.close();

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
   ```
3. FileWriter

   ```
   public void writeData(String dataset) {   
     try {
       URL              url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("datasets.txt");
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(url.getFile(), true);
       FileWriter       out = new FileWriter(getFilePath(), true);

       out.append(dataset);
       out.close();
       fos.close();
     }  catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   ```

Reading the file gave me some trouble too in the beginning but I got it to work with the InputStreamReader, adding the code just in case

```
private void readData() {
    InputStream       is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("datasets.txt");
    InputStreamReader fr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader    br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine())!= null) {      
        dataVec.add(dataset); ...
```

I have never done anything like this before so I´d be grateful for any hints why these approaches dont´t work or any tips that might help, thanks in advance!

Edit:
Based on the explanation I got on why my approach does not work I decided to implement a filechooser to allow the user to select the file they want to work with instead of trying to work with a fixed file in a location relative to the jar. That way I avoid the trouble of having to find the relative path and have the option of working with several separate files containing different datasets.

Answer (score 3):

All sorts of confusion in here:

1. `getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` cannot be written to. You can't convert these to files and pray that you can; resources are abstract concepts; specifically, the abstract concept that definitely makes zero promises about writability. Trivial case in point: Usually 'at deployment', java code is in jar files, and you cannot write to jar files in this manner, you generally don't *want* to write into jar files, and even if you did, a proper secured setup tends to be such that the process cannot write to its own jar file, so this entire exercise is doomed to failure. You don't use these. at all.
2. 'write to the same place the jar is at' is **in general** suspicious. Why? On windows circa 1990 that was extremely common, but it has never been a good place to write per-user files on any OS that wasn't in the DOS/Windows/CPM line/MacOS line, and the 1980s have long since passed us by. It hasn't been a particularly common model on Windows for well over a decade at this point either; instead, you'd write to for example the user's Documents folder. The model itself is inferior: Writing to the same dir the executable code is at implies you could write to the code, and that in general is waiting to get your box p0wned, which is why OSes are abandoning this model in droves.
3. If you *MUST* write to the same folder the jar is in, well, that presumes your code by necessity always runs as a jar which is a bizarre assumption to encode in your source files. What if it's not a jar, such as when you're debugging in eclipse? Next to the classpath entry hosting your class files, so, for your average eclipse project `~/workspace/projname`, as that is the dir containing `~/workspace/projname/bin` which is where the compiled class files are? Okay, you CAN do that. But you don't want to do that (see points 1 and 2). What if the classes are sourced from the network, generated on the fly, or otherwise from a classloader that doesn't have the notion of 'the source classpath entry where this came from is <this jar or this directory>?' - Just pray your code is never deployed in such circumstances? I'd at the very least offer a `-D` based alternate option (which you can read with `System.getProperty`, so, in your java code `String overrideLocation = System.getProperty("islandersproject.homedir");` and to start your app: `java -Dislandersproject.homedir=/Users/islander/documents -jar islandersproject.jar`.

### Okay, so how do I do it?

Well, I said you could. But it is not easy.

For any given class, you can obtain the location where it was loaded from using this construct:

`ClassName.class.getResource("ClassName.class").toString()`

As long as the class in question isn't an inner class, that works. For example:

`System.out.println(String.class.getResource("String.class").toString())` - give that a try.

The string you get could be anything. *IF* it is a file (for example, if the class is `/Users/islander/workspace/islandproject/bin/com/foo/island/islandproject/Island.class`, you get that string, with `file://` tacked to the front. If it's jar, you get something like: `jar:file://Users/islander/blabla/islanderproject.jar!com/foo/island/islandproject/Island.class` - if it's a jmod, it starts with `jmod:` (run this on String on JDK11 or 14 to see it in action), if it's the network or generated on the fly it'll be even more exotic.

If you really are quite sure you want to do this, parse the string.

Note that '.' (the current working directory) is by no means guaranteed to be right; if you run on the command line on windows, for example:

```
C:
CD \foobar
java -jar d:\workspace\dist\islander.jar
```

Then `.` would be the completely unrelated `c:\foobar`, as that was the working dir you started in. Therefore unlikely to be right, even if you luck into that working out when testing (as eclipse and such will set it to a sane place when you start the app from within eclipse).

Comment: As I said, I have never done this before and - obviously quite foolishly - assumed "the same folder the jar is in" would be the easiest location to work with. I do quite like the concept of reading/writing from a textfile I can easily edit outside the program but I am not set on the location or method as this is mainly a small program that I hoped to use to compare some datasets. Any chance you could point me in the direction of how something like that _should_ be done?

Comment: Heh, unfortunately it's a bit messy. The least-effort, at-least-heading-in-the-right-direction solution is to go with the user's home dir (System.getProperty("user.home")) - but on most OSes, you really should get the documents folder that hangs off of that. I don't know of any way to get that though, short of hardcoding the rules for each major OS. This small extra effort would go far: On windows, that+documents. on mac.. same thing. elsewhere, just stick to user.home.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try then!